# overide default text lenth when field is defined

Tags: entities

I can set the size of a text field using the manage filed forms. But I want to do this when the module creats the field. I need the correct setting name and so far I cant google up ant thing that works. Below is the code i'm using to create my fields.  I would appreciate any help.

```
function _bigimage_installed_instances() {
$t = get_t();
return array(

        'bigimage_image' => array(
        'field_name' => 'bigimage_image',
        'label' => $t('Small Image Overview of the Big Image'),
        'settings' => array('file_directory' => 'bigimage/[current-user:url:path]'),
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'image'
        ),
        'display' => array(
            'example_node_list' => array(
                'label' => $t('Small Image overview of the bigimage'),
                'type' => 'image'
            )
        )
    ),
        'bigimage_zif' => array(
        'field_name' => 'bigimage_zif',
        'type' => 'file',
        'label' => $t('bigimage ZIF data'),
        'settings' => array('file_extensions' => 'zif zpp', 'file_directory' => 'bigimage/[current-user:url:path]'),
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'file'

        ),
        'display' => array(
            'example_node_list' => array(
                'label' => $t('ZIF Data of the bigimage'),
                'type' => 'file'
            )
        )
    ),
     'bigimage_vars' => array(
        'field_name' => 'bigimage_vars',
        'label' => $t('Zoomify Viewer Commands'),
        'settings' => array ('#maxlength' => '125' ),
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        'display' => array(
            'example_node_list' => array(
                'label' => $t('Zoomify viewer Commands'),
                'type' => 'text'
            )
        )
    )

);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I finally deduced the answer.  The size setting only seems to work in the widget. the max_length setting only in the field definition. Yep I'm  that dense.